# Slow upload speed in every browser in Windows 10

Tags: networking, browser, upload

I'm experiencing slow upload speeds from every browser (Chrome, Firtefox, Opera, Edge) of 0.7Mbps~1.2Mbps.
When using the Ookla CLI tool, windows store Ookla Speedtest, or Android Speedtest (on WiFi) I get upload speeds of ~3.4Mbps which is consistent with what the ISP should deliver. Same behavior can be observed with other services (OK from any other app, slow in browsers). Download speeds are not affected.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro build 1909, connected with a 1Gpbs wired Ethernet connection to the router.
Tried:

- Resetting the network.
- Using private/incognito modes.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Your upload speeds are normal and correct. For example, I have a download speed of 60Mbps but I download at 7-8Mbps in browsers and such.

Comment: Question is, What you need a browser to upload for? Uploading a file like a resumé on a job platform? Uploading bigger files onto Dropbox or pCloud? (not even sure you can do that with the latter, but you definitely can with the former)

Comment: @NiallUK - Up to 2 weeks ago I would get the expected upload speeds (~3+Mbps) in all browsers.

Comment: @Didier Cloud storage, photo sharing, email atachment etc.

Comment: @Boris Maybe people are using more internet bandwidth than usual due to people working from home and such. Just food for thought

Comment: I think the upload speed from your PC to your router is one thing to consider (quality of your connection over WiFi or Ethernet at home/the office), but mostly, it's true that with the confinement/quarantine in effect in most Western countries, your Internet speed might be affected. I found this article (https://www.addictivetips.com/web/limit-download-speed-in-chrome/) about fine-tuning Chrome's network settings. It's a bit complicated, but you might find something useful in it. Doesn't say if using "0" (zero) is interpreted as "unlimited", as is often the case. Try it out and shout back!